# How to include a thrift file from a different micro service

Tags: microservices, thrift

I am new to micro service and thrift world, I wonder how to include a thrift file from a different micro service.
ex:
In my `user` micro service, I have

```
namespace go user


struct User {
    1: required string id;
    2: required string email;
    3: required string password;
    4: optional list<Order> roles;
}
```

and in my `order` micro service, I have

```
namespace go order


struct Order {
    1: required string id;
    2: required string orderNumber;
}
```

if I also want my User struct to have a list of `Order`, how do I include it from my `order` micro service?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the file, the reference the type with the included prefix, like so:

```
namespace go user

include "order.thrift"

struct User {
    1: required string id;
    2: required string email;
    3: required string password;
    4: optional list<order.Order> roles;
}
```

Recommended read: https://thrift.apache.org/docs/idl.html, escpecially [this example](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob_plain;f=tutorial/tutorial.thrift)